# How to disable devtoolset-8?

Tags: bash, devtoolset, gcc8

I have a bash script that executes the command

`scl enable devtoolset-8 'echo -e "%__ld $(which ld)\n%__nm $(which nm)\n%__objcopy $(which objcopy)\n%__objdump $(which objdump)\n%__strip $(which strip)"'`

After completing the assembly, I need to "turn off" gcc-8.

How can I do this by means of bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to turn anything "off" after the above command, all that it does is prints paths of the main devtoolset executables, e.g.

```
%__ld /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/ld
%__nm /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/nm
%__objcopy /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/objcopy
%__objdump /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/objdump
%__strip /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin/strip
```

When you run a most used `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` command, it is invokes a new bash instance where you have an additional path in your `$PATH` enviroment variable making all the development tools now run from the new location:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[user@hostname ~]$ scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
[user@hostname ~]$ echo $PATH
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[user@hostname ~]$
```

All you need to "turn off" the devtoolset is to exit this bash instance:

```
[user@hostname ~]$ exit
exit
[user@hostname ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
[user@hostname ~]$
```